# AMCharts: можно ли построить график из столбиков, которые растут не снизу, а сверху вниз?

Tags: javascript, диаграммы

Нужен график, где столбики растут не снизу вверх, а сверху вниз. Что-то не пойму, как это сделать. Возможно ли это в amcharts? И может к этой библиотеке есть документация на русском? Тоже не найду никак.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать inversed для AxisRendererY,
как тут:

```
var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(
  am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
  maxPrecision: 0,
  renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
    inversed: true
  })
 })
);
```

[Ссылка на пример в документации](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/reversed-value-axis/)